# Not respecting the Resteasy CORSFilter

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I am Using the resteasy corsFilter, there i am setting the allowedMethods as "GET" only, but it is allowing for all the methods(POST, DELETE).

```
@Provider
public class CorsFeature implements Feature {
    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
    CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter();
    corsFilter.getAllowedOrigins().add("*");
    corsFilter.setAllowedMethods("GET");
    context.register(corsFilter);
    return true;
    }
}
```

Could anyone pls reply, if u know?

Comment: How did you test this? Can you check whether the provider is being picked up when the application is deployed?

Comment: ya it is picked, seen in the log file.

Comment: How are you making the request (with what client)?

Comment: curl and UI as well

Comment: CORS is really only meant for Javascript in the browser. The browser will send a request with specific semantics to handle the CORS, including specific headers. Your attempt and using cURL and a UI Rest client is useless. You should probably do some reading up on CORS to understand how it works and the theory behind it.